# Auto new line in overflowing containers

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to create an app with Flutter and Dart and I was wondering if there was a way to go newline if a container inside a row overflows.
[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyh0q.png), the thing I want to do is to make the "button" go newline if it intersects into another one to make it more readable.
I hope someone can help me, I will link the code also for a better understanding.

```
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40, 0, 0),
    
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(   //I tre bottoni di 'Like', 'Commenta' e 'Condividi'
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          
          children: [
            
            Container(    //Like button
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 20,
                  )
                ]
              ),

              child: Row(   //Contenuto del container, 'child:' perché è il figlio del container
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [   //'Children:[]' perché contiene più elementi
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.thumb_up, color: Colors.white,
                      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                    ),
                  ),

                  Center(
                    child: Text('Like',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40, 0),
              child: Container(    //Comment button
            
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
                
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.green,
            
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
            
                      color: Colors.green,
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 20,
                    )
                  ]
                ),
            
                child: Row(    //Contenuto del secondo bottone (quello centrale)
            
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    
                    Padding(  
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 5, 0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.message, color: Colors.white,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('Commenta',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                ],),
              ),
            ),

            Container(    //Share post button
  
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,

              decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                color: Colors.red,

                boxShadow: [    //Parentesi quadre perché può contenere più proprietà, è perciò una lista
                  BoxShadow(

                    color: Colors.red,
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 20,
                  )
                ]
              ),

              child: Row(   //Contenuto del container

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

                children: [

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.share, color: Colors.white,
                      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('Condividi',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                ]
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
],),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method1: You have to use `Flexible` widget to avoid overflow.

```dart
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40, 0, 0),

      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(   //I tre bottoni di 'Like', 'Commenta' e 'Condividi'
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

            children: [

              Container(    //Like button
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        blurRadius: 20,
                      )
                    ]
                ),

                child: Row(   //Contenuto del container, 'child:' perché è il figlio del container
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [   //'Children:[]' perché contiene più elementi
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.thumb_up, color: Colors.white,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                      ),
                    ),

                    Flexible(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('Like',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40, 0),
                child: Container(    //Comment button

                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,

                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.green,

                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(

                          color: Colors.green,
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 20,
                        )
                      ]
                  ),

                  child: Row(    //Contenuto del secondo bottone (quello centrale)

                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 5, 0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.message, color: Colors.white,
                          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text('Commenta',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],),
                ),
              ),

              Container(    //Share post button

                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,

                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.red,

                      boxShadow: [    //Parentesi quadre perché può contenere più proprietà, è perciò una lista
                        BoxShadow(

                          color: Colors.red,
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 20,
                        )
                      ]
                  ),

                  child: Row(   //Contenuto del container

                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

                      children: [

                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.share, color: Colors.white,
                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text('Condividi',
                            style: TextStyle(

                              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

**Edited**
Method 2:

```dart
   Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40, 0, 0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            //I tre bottoni di 'Like', 'Commenta' e 'Condividi'
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  //Like button
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 20,
                        )
                      ]),

                  child: Row(
                    //Contenuto del container, 'child:' perché è il figlio del container
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      //'Children:[]' perché contiene più elementi
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.thumb_up,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                        ),
                      ),

                      Flexible(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Like',
                            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  //Comment button

                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),

                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 20,
                        )
                      ]),

                  child: Row(
                    //Contenuto del secondo bottone (quello centrale)

                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.message,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Commenta',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    //Share post button
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        boxShadow: [
                          //Parentesi quadre perché può contenere più proprietà, è perciò una lista
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 20,
                          )
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                        //Contenuto del container

                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.share,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text(
                              'Condividi',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ])),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Method 3: Try with `Wrap` to make the buttons in multiple lines but text will be in single line

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40, 0, 0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  //Like button
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 20,
                        )
                      ]),

                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    //Contenuto del container, 'child:' perché è il figlio del container
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      //'Children:[]' perché contiene più elementi
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.thumb_up,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                        ),
                      ),

                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Like',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  //Comment button

                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),

                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 20,
                        )
                      ]),

                  child: Row(
                    //Contenuto del secondo bottone (quello centrale)
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.message,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Commenta',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    //Share post button
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        boxShadow: [
                          //Parentesi quadre perché può contenere più proprietà, è perciò una lista
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 20,
                          )
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                        //Contenuto del container
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.share,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text(
                              'Condividi',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ])),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: It worked but what if I don't want the text to disappear and make the container go to a new line and keep the text visible?

Comment: Checkout my edit to support for your requirement

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: Have tried second snippet?

Comment: You don't want new line? Then we may need to use `Wrap`

Comment: Wrap does't work I don't know why I have already tried that like 3 times

Comment: Do want text and buttons should be in single line?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'd like the buttons to move from all 3 in one row to like 3 in 3 different rows... I Know I should use ```Wrap``` but it doesn't work I don't know if it's my error putting it in the wrong place or other stuff....

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the problem, I put the `Wrap` widget in the wrong position and now it works as needed.
Here's the code to help others who have the same problem.

````
Wrap(children: [

                Row(   //I tre bottoni di 'Like', 'Commenta' e 'Condividi'
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  
                  children: [
                    
                    Container(    //Like button
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 20,
                          )
                        ]
                      ),
              
                      child: Row(   //Contenuto del container, 'child:' perché è il figlio del container
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [   //'Children:[]' perché contiene più elementi
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.thumb_up, color: Colors.white,
                              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                            ),
                          ),
              
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Like',
                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40, 0),
                      child: Container(    //Comment button
                    
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
                        
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          color: Colors.green,
                    
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                    
                              color: Colors.green,
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 20,
                            )
                          ]
                        ),
                    
                        child: Row(    //Contenuto del secondo bottone (quello centrale)
                    
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            
                            Padding(  
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 5, 0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.message, color: Colors.white,
                                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              child: Text('Commenta',
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],),
                      ),
                    ),
              
                    Container(    //Share post button
                      
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
              
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.red,
              
                        boxShadow: [    //Parentesi quadre perché può contenere più proprietà, è perciò una lista
                          BoxShadow(
              
                            color: Colors.red,
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 20,
                          )
                        ]
                      ),
              
                      child: Row(   //Contenuto del container
              
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              
                        children: [
              
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.share, color: Colors.white,
                              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Condividi',
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ]
                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

              ],
    ```
````